# pass object from one page to another page NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getserversideprops

I want to pass nested object data from one page to the next page. I want to pass the object. We can not use localStorage or sessionStorage because we have to consume object values from getServerSideProps. We do not use here router query as it passes a query that takes key pair value.

Comment: Have you considering adding this data into a context provider? https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Smaiil
I am coming up with a solution. We can not send an object through localStorage. We can work through it via query.

```
const queryData = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3',
}

router.push({
    pathname: 'pathname',
    query: queryData,
  },
  'pathname' // use this to clear query strings like key value from URL
);
```

This way we can send query data and do getServerSideProps implementation to the respective page. refer below

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {

```
 try {
    const response = await wretch(
      `API URL`
    )
      .post(query)
      .json();
    const scheme = response.data;
    return {
      props: { scheme },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` run on the server so they do not have any relation with your components and your hooks, so there is no way that they have access to any `provider` or any `hook`.

but since `getServerSideProps` runs on every `request` you can use the request to pass data to it. one solution is to pass data in the `url`.

> We do not use here router query as it passes a query that takes key pair value

you can pass an object with router query you just have to `stringify` it before passing it then `parse` data when you recieve it

let suppose that you have `page A` with `getServerSideProps` you can call it like this :

```js
const router = useRouter();
router.push({
pathname: '/url_of_page_A',
query: { 
data: JSON.stringify( { a: 'value', b: 'another value'} ) ;
},
});
```

Now in your `page A` inside `getServerSideProps` you can access `data` via context query :

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
const data = JSON.parse(context.query.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Link** component from `next/link`, something like:

```
  <Link 
      href={{ 
          pathname: 'path-to-your-page', 
          query: 'data you want to pass' 
          }} 
  >
      You other page
  </ Link>
```

From your other page, you can then benefit form the `useRouter` **nextjs** hook:

```
const router = useRouter();
const dataFromPreviousPage = router.query;
```

Comment: it will showing data in browser adress bar!!!